# Are there any goals for the update manager behavior with Unity?

Tags: update-manager, ayatana

The notification tray approach to the update manager has been discarded in favor of a pop-under window to increase awareness of updates. With a complete redesign in shell behavior upcoming are there any plans on changing the behavior still some more? Will the behavior remain largely unchanged - a minimized icon (possibly flashing?) in the launcher?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are, according to this blueprint: https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/packageselection-foundations-n-update-notifier-refactor
It's details are however, at least for me, mysterious.

Comment: It looks to me like these were (mostly under-the-cover) changes planned for Maverick that never happened. Whilst they may still happen, that particular blueprint was written well before the suggestion of "Unity by default" so they don't really answer the question here.